# Linked List in Java: Displaying last node incorrectly

Tags: java, list, linked-list

Following are the two classes:

```
        import java.io.*;
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node link;
    BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    void accept()throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        data=Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
    }
}


import java.io.*;
class LinkedList
{
    BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Node start=new Node();
    void create()throws IOException
    {
        Node n=new Node();
        n.accept();
        start.link=n;
    }
    void addbeg()throws IOException
    {
        Node n=new Node();
        n.accept();
        n.link=start.link;
        start.link=n;
    }
    void addend()throws IOException
    {
        Node n=new Node();
        n.accept();
        Node n1=new Node();
        n1=start.link;
        while(n1.link!=null)
        {
            n1=n1.link;
        }
        n1.link=n;
        n.link=null;
    }
    void addafter()throws IOException
    {
        boolean flag=false;
        System.out.println("Enter data after which node is to be added: ");
        int d=Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
        Node n=new Node();
        n.accept();
        Node n1=start.link;
        while(n1.link!=null)
        {
            if(n1.data==d)
            {
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
            n1=n1.link;
        }
        if(flag==true)
        {
            n.link=n1.link;
            n1.link=n;
        }
        else
        System.out.println("Data is not present in the list");
    }
    void addbefore()throws IOException
    {
        boolean flag=false;
        Node n=new Node();
        n.accept();
        System.out.println("Enter the data before which node is to be added: ");
        int d=Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
        Node n1=start.link;
        Node prev=start;
        while(n1.link!=null)
        {
            if(n1.data==d)
            {
                n.link=n1;
                prev.link=n;
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                prev=n1;
                n1=n1.link;
            }
        }
        if(flag==false)
        {
            System.out.println("Data not found");
        }
    }
    void delbeg()
    {
        Node n=start.link;
        start.link=n.link;
        n.link=null;
    }
    void delend()
    {
        Node n=start.link;
        Node prev=start;
        while(n.link!=null)
        {
            prev=n;
            n=n.link;
        }
        prev.link=null;
    }
    void delspecific()throws IOException
    {
        boolean flag=false;
        System.out.println("Enter data to be deleted: ");
        int d=Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
        Node n=start.link;
        Node prev=start;
        while(n.link!=null)
        {
            if(n.data==d)
            {
                prev.link=n.link;
                n.link=null;
                flag=true;
            }
            else
            {
                prev=n;
                n=n.link;
            }
        }
        if(flag==false)
        {
            System.out.println("Data is not present in the list");
        }
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Linked List: ");
        Node n=start.link;
        do
        {
            System.out.print(n.data+" -&gt; ");
            n=n.link;
        }
        while(n.link!=null);
        System.out.println();
    }
    void main()throws IOException
    {
        boolean flag=false;
        while(!flag)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter choice: ");
            System.out.println("1. Create ");
            System.out.println("2. Add at the Beginning ");
            System.out.println("3. Add at the End ");
            System.out.println("4. Add after a particular node ");
            System.out.println("5. Add before a particular node ");
            System.out.println("6. Delete at the Beginning ");
            System.out.println("7. Delete at the End ");
            System.out.println("8. Delete a specific node ");
            System.out.println("9. View ");
            System.out.println("10. End ");
            int ch=Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1:create();
                break;
                case 2:addbeg();
                break;
                case 3:addend();
                break;
                case 4:addafter();
                break;
                case 5:addbefore();
                break;
                case 6:delbeg();
                break;
                case 7:delend();
                break;
                case 8:delspecific();
                break;
                case 9:display();
                break;
                case 10:flag=true;
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute any function and view the linked list, the last node is always missing. I have been working on this program for the past four hours and was surprised when the last node was not displayed. Help please

Comment: Please, be kind and format your code. It's quite hard to read with no indentation.

Comment: When something like this happens, Debug by printing some info. You could also step through the code, but that's probably not necessary. I haven't looked at your code, but it'll probably take minutes to find the error.

Comment: I don't know whats going wrong... It should be correct... if anyone could copy and run this on their system, it would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the huge program but that's what I have created working on it for the last four hours... Its easy to understand though

Comment: In your `display` method you start with `Node n=start.link;`. Why not `Node n=start;`? Seems like you're missing the first node

Comment: Also...should be easy to fix: think about changing your `do--while` for a `while--do`

Comment: @Tikli The first thing I'd do would be to print what's happening to find out what's not working as expected, but I won't do it for you. If you fail to understand something at that step I'll be happy to help.

Comment: But isn't the start node empty? I mean its just a node that points to the first node, which holds the first data

Comment: @JuliánUrbano tried that but then it shows something like

Comment: 0 -> 4 -> 3 -> even though when creating I gave the value 2

Comment: I see...yes, your `start` node is empty (by the way, this is not how we usually do this; start node should have the first item). Take a look at your `display` loop, and think about what happens when you reach the second to last node here `n=n.link; } while(n.link!=null);`

Comment: Your error is in your `display()` method, not the linked list itself. Trying thinking about what each step of your loop is doing and walking through it.

Comment: I was first using the while(n.link!=null)... loop only but then I thought that maybe I am missing on the last node that way... I changed it to do while but no difference

Comment: almost there...try `n!=null`...hell do it on paper...understand what's going on!

Comment: @JuliánUrbano Works!!! Proper display of linked list! Thanks a million, friend; got a test tomorrow on data structures and had got stuck... if u could kindly explain where I was going wrong...

Comment: Your problem was that you were checking the link off of your last node before you printed it. At the end of the loop you were reassigning `n` to the next node then checking if it had an additional link. In the case of the last node it did not have an additional link so the loop exited before printing the last node. Hope this helps!

Comment: k now i understand... what a simple mistake... thanks 2 everyone for helping out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** the `start` node does *not* hold an item, it just points to the first item's node.

The problem is in the `display` method:

```
Node n = start.link;
do {
    System.out.print(n.data+" -&gt; ");
    n = n.link;
} while(n.link != null);
```

Imagine the point where `n` is the second to last node. We enter the loop, print the second to last item, and set `n=n.link`, that is, the last node. Next we check `n.link!=null`, which turns out to be false because we are in the last node, so we don't enter the loop again and the last item is therefore not printed.

Note also that if you display an empty list you'll have a `NullPointerException`: `n=start.link` will set `n=null`, because you don't have any nodes. Then, you enter the loop and try to print, which will raise the exception.

It can be fixed in several ways. For instance, we can check the current node `n` before actually printing:

```
Node n = start.link;
while(n != null){
    System.out.print(n.data+" -&gt; ");
    n = n.link;
}
```

Comment: understood it fully now...thnx a million